# Windows HotKey in C# App

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-api-code-pack, registerhotkey

Hi I am working on an C# Windows App that uses key combination like CTRL+A and CTRL+Z outside the app (running in background).

I tried `RegisterHotKeys` tutorials but i have an issue. When pressing CTRL+A only my method is executed and Windows default action is never executed. I want to execute first windows action and only after that action to execute my method for that key.

For example:

```
CTRL+A

1) Select All

2) My code
```

Some code below:

```
private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ObjectsList = new List<Data>();

            thisWindow = FindWindow(null, "myform");

            RegisterHotKey(thisWindow, 1, (uint)fsKeyMod.Control, (uint)Keys.A);

        }


        private enum fsKeyMod
        {
            Control = 0x0002,
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message keyPressed)
        {

            base.WndProc(ref keyPressed);

            if (keyPressed.Msg == 0x0312)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("apasat cv...");
            }

        }
```

I need the solution as soon as possible.
Thank You!

Comment: Are you trying to overload global keyboard shortcuts? If that's the case, consider not doing it at all. It will result in the most user hostile UI experience imaginable.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could fix this (with message forwarding or dispatching for example), this is certainly not recommended.

Better use a **unique key-combination** instead.